# MAMP "Extras" Wordpress site causes error ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: wordpress, mamp, mamp-pro

In short, I can create a new MAMP Pro 3 host with success and then download and install Wordpress 4.0 via MAMP Pro's "Extra's" feature also seemingly with success (no errors, ) ...yet it doesn't turn out that way as the browser says, "Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

Full Details:  Hi, I've just installed MAMP Pro for the first time on Mac OS 10.9.5 with all the default settings, the WebStart page loaded in the browser, php looks to be running fine.  The problem I'm having occurs when running a preliminary test of MAMP by trying the Extras feature and installing Wordpress 4.0.  I get no indication that anything went wrong with the default install yet clicking the button next to the Server Name "Open the hosts web page in a browser"... I am greeted with an error in Google Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc....

"This webpage is not available. Google Chrome's connection attempt to  was rejected. Error code: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Google Chrome's connection attempt to testwpextra.dev was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.

- Check your Internet connection
- Allow Chrome to access the network in your firewall or antivirus settings.
- Check your proxy settings
  "

I'm not using a proxy, I am running apache as my local user and have confirmed the document root is owned by the same user (with read/write permissions), I turned off firewall/littlesnitch just to be sure, same result in various browsers.

I read some fella saying something about setting up his host with IPv6 but I'm using the MAMP control panel to manage the process for me and don't see settings of that nature.  Maybe this is done via the Extended tab with directory or VirtualHost parameters, I don't know... wish I did. Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing MAMPs ports from the default 8888 etc... to 80,443,3306 (on MAMPs General tab).  Now all my includes are broken because MAMP doesn't allow "php_value" in htaccess files...one step at a time i guess. =]